# I upgraded the firmware on my Cisco RV320 router, now no connected devices can access the internet

Tags: networking, router

I upgraded the firmware on my Cisco RV320 Dual Gigabit WAN VPN Router to version 1.4.2.17 found here https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/routers/rv320-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/model.html#~tab-downloads. The firmware hadn't been upgraded for many years,possibly up to 7, and me being a new hire decided to upgrade it. I created a backup of the router before I did the upgrade as well. The router does not support WiFi connections, only direct Ethernet connections.

After the upgrade completed, no devices connected to the router could access the internet. They showed a connection was there, but just no internet.

The strange part though is on the router configuration webpage at 192.168.1.1 under the system settings tab it shows the router is connected to the internet.

[image]

I've looked for similar posts but couldn't find anyone describing having the configuration page saying the router is connected but connected devices are not.

This in an emulator for the Cisco RV320 router's configuration page that I am using https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/RV320_Emulators/RV320_Emulator_v1.1.0.09/default.htm in case it helps at all.

Comment: If the router can access then you can set the client with the DNS server as the router's IP.

Comment: It just says a cable is connected. That doesn’t mean anything, really. Check all configuration: It could have reverted to default/different settings in some aspects.

Comment: Any idea which setting would be affected specifically? I checked my VPNS, IPv4 settings, and static IPs. Everything seems to be in order.

Comment: @MichaelBay I have to keep a static IP as we have VPNs setup already with multiple vendors.

Comment: Static/dynamic IPs and DNS server are totally unrelated. Any person dealing with networking (VPNs, etc.) should know that.

Comment: @MichaelBay I have to keep a static IP for the router. Could you please explain a little more regarding the DNS? I have the option to set the DNS in router setup wizard but am unsure what to use https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/RV320_Emulators/RV320_Emulator_v1.1.0.09/default.htm.

Comment: Not in the router (assuming it really connects to the outside), it's in the devices that *may* still have an old configuration using the old DNS server (gateway). From the clients: Ping www.google.com and it'll probably fail. Now ping 8.8.8.8 and if it succeeds there's your problem right there.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 with my Cisco router but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who encounters this issue I was able to solve it with help from a Cisco representative. A+ for their support. My major issue was upgrading from my older version corrupted my router configuration and my backup config file was corrupt.

I was on version 1.4.2 of the firmware, and the rep recommended downgrading to the 1.3.2 version as it's more stable. This was step 1. After doing so, it removed all configurations for my router, as it warns you it will if you downgrade the firmware.

Step 2 was going to Setup > Network > WAN Setting Table > WAN1 > Edit and setting up my static IP manually. After this I immediately had an internet connection.

[image]

Step 3 was setting up all my VPNs as I had previously. After completed, all my programs using the VPNs worked fine.

If anyone runs into this issue or something similar and my solution above doesn't work I highly recommend reaching out to Cisco small business support.